# How to test multiple inheritance in Javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, dojo, multiple-inheritance

I'm using dojo / AMD to create a new object and am using instanceof to test it.

Currently the code is this:

```
var object = new (declare([_BaseField, ValidationTextBox]))({
      params: someParams
});


console.log(object instanceof _BaseField); // Returns true.
console.log(object instanceof ValidationTextBox); // Returns false.
```

My question is, show can I test this if instanceof doesn't recognize multiple inheritance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript only has single inheritance, and therefore a linear prototype chain. *a instanceof B* tests if *B* is in the prototype chain of *a*.

Emulating multiple inheritance, dojo takes the first object as the prototype, and treats all remaining objects as mixins.

Therefore the objects _BaseField and *ValidationTextBox* are not used equally.

To test that *object* also inherits from *ValidationTextBox* the dojo way, you have to test the dojo way, i.e.

```
object.isInstanceOf(ValidationTextBox) // true
```

Comment: This was a lifesaver. Excited that dojo has method as well -- would love to amp up documentation in this area. Thank you very much!